# What VB.NET Rounding methods do I need to call to ge the perferred results?

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 rounding options: None, Standard, Up, Down

If they choose None and the number is 108.7879,  I just want to display 108.78 with no rounding.  I know I probably can use Math.Ceil for Up and Math.Floor for Down, but I am not sure what to use for None or Standard.

If they choose Standard:

106.78 should round up to 107

106.49 should round down to 106

If they choose Up:

106.49 should round up to 107

106.52 should round up to 107

If they choose Down:

106.78 should round down to 106

106.49 should round down to 106

Comment: You need to ask the customer/end user of your software, not us. I'm not trying to be cute. What do the stakeholders want to see?

Comment: @Paul Sasik, I believe you are confused, that is what the customer wants, I just want to know the correct vb.net methods to call to get the correct results.

Comment: In that case I think you're just missing Math.Round for your "standard" rounding. No rounding for none... just display the value as is.

Comment: Are you serious?  You're not sure what method to call to do rounding?  Did you even look at the documentation for [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx)?  Specifically the [MidpointRounding Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx)?

Comment: for none, i want to just return 106.7879 to 106.78, so technically not as is, but with only two decimal places.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, yes in fact I did, but I wanted to just make sure I am doing it right.

Comment: +1 for the question because, although it's not the best written question I have ever seen, it doesn't deserve -2.

Comment: I was curious about that also MarkJ.  Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are what you want:

- Standard: `Math.Round`
- Down: `Math.Floor`
- Up: `Math.Ceiling`
- None: `Math.Round(n, 2)` the second parameter specifies the number of digits to round to

So this code:

```
imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
imports System

public module MyModule
    Sub Main()
        'If they choose Standard:
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(106.78) & " should round up to 107")
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(106.49 ) & " should round down to 106")

        'If they choose Up:
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(106.49) & "  should round up to 107")
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(106.52) & "  should round up to 107")

        'If they choose Down:
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(106.78) & "  should round down to 106")    
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(106.49) & "  should round down to 106")

        'If they choose None:
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(106.78455, 2) & "  should round down to 106.78")   
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(106.49456, 2) & "  should round down to 106.49")

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
end module
```

Will result in this output:

```
107 should round up to 107
106 should round down to 106
107  should round up to 107
107  should round up to 107
106  should round down to 106
106  should round down to 106
106.78  should round down to 106.78
106.49  should round down to 106.49
```

Comment: Paul, I am returning a decimal, so for nothing, I get a value like 106.78393939393, but I just want to display the first 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Xai: Plz see my edit. 2nd, overloaded param to Round specifies number of digits.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, Snippet Compiler is great for code samples like this. You can mess around with logic and not worry about "dirtying" your main dev code.

Comment: Where can I find snippet compiler?

Comment: For none, I am doing Math.Truncate(value * 100) / 100 because it will round a number up or down such as 100.678 to 100.68

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question.  You're pretty much answering yourself in the post.  For None, just show the result as is, without any kind of rounding or truncation of decimals.

Public Enum RoundOption
  None,
  Standard,
  Up,
  Down
End Enum

'Maybe have this variable somewhere global, where you only need to set which option to use once. If you don't want a global variable, then send the option as a parameter to the method.
Private roundOption As RoundOption

Public Function Round(ByVal value As Double) As Double
  Select Case rountOption
    Case RoundOption.None
      Return value
    Case RoundOption.Up
      Return Math.Ceiling(value)
    Case RoundOption.Down
      Return Math.Floor(value)
    Case RoundOption.Standard
      Return Math.Truncate(value * 100) / 100
  End Select
End Function

Comment: that is part of my issue, how do take 106.7879 and truncate it to two decimal places and with Standard, how do I ensure that vb.net will do the proper rounding.

Comment: Try this for the standard option: Return Math.Truncate(value * 100) / 100

Comment: The code in the selected answer has a bug for the OP requirements. If None is chosen, Math.Round(100.678, 2) will return 100.68, instead of the 100.67 the OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Math.Truncate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx)

Comment: ... which satisfies neither of his options.

Comment: Math.Truncate return all the integral portion. I want 106.7879 to return 106.78, but not round the value up to 106.79 for example

Comment: It will round down for positive and up for negative values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) method for standard rounding. For 'None' you should not call anything. The others you have answered yourself (Math.Ceili and Math.Floor)

EDIT: There is a [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) overload to specify the number of digits

Comment: I understand that with None I should do nothing, but I don't want to return 106.7838383939393 for example, I would just want to return 106.78

Comment: Will Math.Round(106.7879,2) round the 2 decimal places?